# TWO Insert updates in one webpage issues

Tags: php, mysql

I have two insert updates on my webpage, i have done this in the past without any issue, however, today i am having major issues, the first insert update works perfectly, but the second doesn't (on pressing the submit button nothing appears in the db table) even through the exactly the same script is being used.

I am not sure if its the two insert updates in one webpage, or if it is the fact that i need to close the db after the first insert update, which i haven't.

The db table i am trying to insert into has a unique key, i am also connected to my db or a complete different problem all together. Extremely frustrated. Please help

**The second insert update**

```
   $Restaurant_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['restaurant_id']);
                 if (isset($_POST['Save_changes'])) {
        $code = $_POST['Pcode'];


        $insert_ = "INSERT INTO Delivery_Pcode
  (Pcode,Restaurant_ID) VALUES(?,?)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE 
    Pcode  = ?
    ,Restaurant_ID  = ?";


        $r_query = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_);
        //new
        // $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_c);
        //debugging
        //$run_query = $dbc->prepare($insert_Delex);

        $r_query->bind_param('sisi', $code,$Restaurant_id,$code,$Restaurant_id);
        // THIS now executes the above transaction, returns TRUE if successful - issdissd duplicate update
        if (!$r_query->execute()) {
            $insertEr = "There was an error inserting data: " . $r_query->error;
        }

        print "affeted rows:" . $r_query->affected_rows; //how many records affected? 
        $r_query->free_result(); // Frees memory on completion 
        $r_query->close(); //closes this action 
    }
```

HTML

```
  <form id="delivery_pcodes" action ="Franchise_postcodes.php?restaurant_id=<?php echo $_GET['restaurant_id'] ?>&Franchise=<?php echo $_GET['Franchise']; ?>" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="pcode" id="pcode"  value="<?php echo $pcodes; ?>"  placeholder="e.g LS1,LS2,LS3" tabindex="2">
            <input type="number" name="pcode_price" id="pcode_price"  value=""  placeholder="e.g 3.50" tabindex="2">

            <button type="submit" id="Save_changes" name="Save_changes" value="Save Changes">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Save changes
            </button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Share Your html also

Comment: @Rishi added see above

Comment: What is your `PRIMARY`/`UNIQUE KEY` that you have for your `ON DUPLICATE KEY`? If it is `Restaurant_ID`, then there is no need to do `Restaurant_ID  = ?`, as you are not updating that value, and if you were, then it would never invoke the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` so it would just insert a new row.

Comment: @Sean Primary Key is Del_pcode_id, which is a AI, the unique Key(s) is a combination of Restaurant_ID and Pcode, as one Restaurant can have many Pcodes but a Pcode cannot have many Restaurant_ID's. The Restaurant ID also must be inserted into the table, from a string url

Comment: I still don't understand the purpose of your `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. If you have a `UNIQUE KEY(Pcode,Restaurant_ID)`, then if you change the value of the `Pcode`, you will never invoke the `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, and if you don't change the `Pcode` value then you are just updating `Pcode` and `Restaurant_ID` to the same values. So there is no need for a `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, as why do an update with no changes? Your `UNIQUE KEY` should probably be on `Pcode` only, as that would place it in the table only once, as it can only have 1 `Restaurant_ID`.

Comment: @Sean I have 4 columns, but 2 columns that may be constantly changed by the user. Okay thank you. I will take on your suggestion regarding the unique key

Answer (score 0):

In this code, you are execute `$code,$Restaurant_id` twice.

```
 $r_query->bind_param('sisi', $code,$Restaurant_id,$code,$Restaurant_id);
```

Comment: This isn't the answer. If you look at his query there are 4 parameters, and he's binding all 4.